# 50% of Manhattan Zips returning Manhattan other 50% returning New York

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-geocoder

In a recent project Google API is being referenced to pull city information from a zip code. 
A Brooklyn or Queens Zip should return Brooklyn or queens and it does exactly that. When dealing with Manhattan the standard format is to return New York so that the address reads New York, New York. 
The google API is split 50/50 returning the following.

```
10034 - New York
10040 - New York
10033 - New York
10032 - Manhattan
10039 - New York
10031 - Manhattan
10030 - Manhattan
10037 - New York
10035 - Manhattan
10027 - Manhattan
10025 - Manhattan
10029 - Manhattan
10128 - Manhattan
10028 - New York
10044 - New York
```

I have only provided the first half of the Zip code map but the split continues.
Can this be fixed to return New York, New York with out having to hard code it.

Comment: Have you looked at the sublocality for those results?

Comment: I looked at zip 10032, and it came up as "New York, NY" for me.

Comment: What's even worse is that geocoding "New York, New York" with Google's geocoder returns the `New York, New York Casino in Las Vegas` as its first result.